# Copying cells from one worksheet onto another if cell in column C = 0 with macro

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first post on SO, so please forgive me for any faux pas. I'll try to adhere to the rules of the website.

What am I trying to do?

I'm trying to copy a cell from column A if cell = 0 on column C of the same row from sheet "raw data" onto column A of sheet "ONE".

What have I tried so far?

Here's my code:

```
Sub SortMyColumns()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim descColumn As Integer

    descColumn = 3

    lastRow = Worksheets("raw data").Cells(Rows.Count, descColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Worksheets("raw data").Cells(i, 3).Value = "0" Then
            Worksheets("raw data").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("ONE").Cells(i, 1).Value

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

What's the problem?

The code correctly detects cells in column A if on the same row cells in column C = 0, but instead of copying the cell from "raw data" and pasting it into sheet "ONE", it simply deletes what's in column A of sheet "raw data" and doesn't paste anything.

I am still figuring these things out, but none of the answers I've seen on SO seem to help, which is why I've decided to post.

Thanks for your time guys!

Aleks

Comment: Just use a filter, and then copy the visible cells from column A.

Comment: You've got the order backwards too. You're writing values from the "ONE" sheet to the "raw data" sheet as it is now.

Comment: `{AssignmentTarget} = {AssignedValue}`

Comment: AMAZING everyone!! Thank you so much, it worked now. Appreciate ya'll looking into this!